# terra: plet() to plot a quantitative field of SpatVector

Tags: r, terra

I have problems producing reasonable plots of quantitative fields in SpatVector objects.
Using data from the example on the help page:

```
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
plet(v, "POP", tiles="")
```

[image]
Note the color scale is not appropriate for a continuous variable and the legend is not ordered.

```
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
#correct plot:
plet(r, tiles="")
```

[image]

```
#but
rp <- as.points(r)
plet(rp, "elevation", tiles="")
```

[image]

It looks like the quantitative field is plotted as if it were qualitative, but
I do not see specific options in the parameter list.

Comment: Apparently, one needs to install the development version of leaflet to run this code.

Comment: Tested with github versions of both terra (terra_1.7-34) and leaflet (leaflet_2.1.2.9000). Note the problem is not errors, but inappropriate plots. I edit to include screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Reported as a bug to https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1177
Follow there the issue.

Comment: Solved in github version, see  https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1177